# Returning a single int from int[] method in java

Tags: java, arrays, int

I am trying to make a method 'difference' that finds the largest number in an int array and returns the int to the main method. I am getting an error telling me I can't convert an int array to an int. How can I make this work? I don't want to return an entire array. Thanks a lot

```
public class bigDiff{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int[] arr = new int[] {7, 6, 8, 9};
        difference(arr);
    }

    public static int difference (int[] input){
        int smallest = input[0];
        int largest = input[0];

        for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++){
            if(input[i] >= largest){
                largest = input[i];
            } else if(input[i] <= input[largest]){
                smallest = input[i];
            }
        } 
        return largest;

    }   
}
```

Comment: `input[i] <= input[largest]` <- that a typo? shouldn't that be `input[i] <= smallest`? I would expect that line to result in ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException quite often.

Comment: Apart from that i really cannot reproduce the error you are getting. Are you sure you are running the code you posted?

Comment: Damn. That was a silly mistake. Thanks for the help. I got it working

Comment: Also, shouldn't you `return largest - smallest`? Otherwise, why is the method called `difference` and why do you keep track of `smallest` at all?

Comment: This question is not related with It's code.

Comment: @SamDev Indeed. I have voted to close. The stated problem could not be reproduced with the given code sample.

Answer (score 0):

watch this line of code

```
else if(input[i] <= input[largest]){
            smallest = input[i];
        }
```

`input[largest]` , first time largest value is 7 means input[7],and your array size is only 4.so this not work.

`input[largest]` instead use `input[i]`.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to explain a few things:
First, your declaration of the array is quite weird, you should declare: `int[] arr = {7, 6, 8, 9};`
Second, `difference` function returns an int, what are you doing with it? nothing.. try printing it.. `System.out.println(difference(arr));`
Third, you're trying to get the largest number, why do you need the smallest number? Even the compiler warns you for a variable which isn't being used.
So your `difference` function should be like:

```
int largest = input[0];
for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++){
    if(input[i] > largest)
        largest = input[i];
} 
return largest;
```

** You don't need to do anything if `input[i] == largest`, so checking `if(input[i] > largest)` is enough.
Good Luck :)

Answer (score 0):

You have declared an array i.e `int[] arr = new int[] {7, 6, 8, 9}` length of this array is 4 but here in the difference function,

```
for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++){
        if(input[i] >= largest){
            largest = input[i];
        } else if(input[i] <= input[largest]){
            smallest = input[i];
        }
    }
```

when you are comparing this in **else if(input[i] <= input[largest])** then it will generate error because in the first iteration **largest=7** and in next iteration it will go in else if where **input[1]<=input[7]** is checked so the array out of bound exception will be generated.

I think you want to get the largest element in the array so instead of doing this you can short the array and access the largest element easily.

Answer (score 0):

Problems:
1. `largest` is used as an index (i.e., `input[largest]`), which may cause`ArrayOutOfBoundsException` if `largest` is larger than the array length 
2. `largest` is used in the `if` to set `smallest`
3. `difference` returns the `largest` element instead of the difference between the `largest` and `smallest` elements
4. Return value of `difference` isn't used (not a real problem, but you can't see the output of `difference`)

Otherwise the (amended) program below works:

```
public class bigDiff{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int[] arr = new int[] {7, 6, 8, 9};
        System.out.println(difference(arr)); // problem 4 was here
    }

    public static int difference (int[] input){
        int smallest = input[0];
        int largest = input[0];

        for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++){
            if(input[i] >= largest){
                largest = input[i];
            } else if(input[i] <= smallest){ // problems 1 and 2 were here
                smallest = input[i];
            }
        } 
        return largest - smallest; // problem 3 was here

    }   
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This should work just fine:

```
public static int difference (int[] input){
    int smallest = input[0];
    int largest = input[0];

    for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++){
        if(input[i] > largest){
            largest = input[i];
        } else if(input[i] < smallest){
            smallest = input[i];
        }
    } 
    return largest;

}
```

Also there is no point in keeping the smallest value when you're interested only in the largest.